# Which resolution is best if I want to print a document?

Tags: resolution

I am in a project where I need to do several documents. I did this size for a test:

- A: 203x218cm, 300dpi
- B: 203x218cm, 72dpi
- C: 80x86cm, 300dpi

I would like to know some opinion about my files.

1. Which document works best if I want to print a document with good quality?
2. It's a document in Photoshop

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot option D: **None of the previous**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions you mention above are very, very large. Providing they are correct, either of the 300dpi files will print well (though for that matter, a 200cm+ image at 72dpi will print well on most applications).

As a general rule, printing a 300dpi image at 100% scale will give you a good result.